# Xpath query- trying to locate relative path of element in table

Tags: xpath

I am trying to locate the element with text 'cccc cccc' but to no avail

I have tried //*[@class='eline']//*[contains(.,'cccc cccc')] but to no avail

Here is the source code

```
<tr class="eline">
<tr>
<td class="norm" nowrap=""/>
<td class="norm" nowrap="">
<td class="norm" nowrap="">
<td class="norm" nowrap="">cccc cccc </td>
<td class="norm" nowrap="">99999 </td>
<td class="norm" nowrap=""/>
<td>
<td class="norm" nowrap="">
<td class="norm" nowrap="">
<td class="norm" nowrap="">testcase33 testcase33 </td>
<td class="norm" nowrap="">33100 </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

XPath should look like this:

```
//tr[@class='eline']/td[@class='norm' and contains(.,'cccc cccc')]
```

Comment: Hi that this not return any values for some reason

Comment: The XPath is correct, maybe it is because you use selenium and have to get the text with `.text()`